# Repeat rows in MS Excel Using VB Module

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this VBA snippet in MS Excel that allows me to duplicate rows by the "X" number entered in popup dialogue box. I want to change it in such a way that it only repeat row 3,5,7 and so on but not row 1.

```vb
Sub insertrows()
Dim I As Long
Dim xCount As Integer
LableNumber:
xCount = Application.InputBox("Number of Rows", "Popup menu", , , , , , 1)
If xCount < 1 Then
MsgBox "The entered number of rows is error ,please enter again"
GoTo LableNumber
End If
For I = Range("A" & Rows.CountLarge).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
Rows(I).Copy
Rows(I).Resize(xCount).Insert
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not ask Kutools for help modifying their code? If you already paid for the service, they might be willing to customize it to fit your usage.

Comment: I am not using Kutools, the code is taken from their website. The Kutools mentioned in code is just caption of popup dialogue box asking for number of rows to repeat.